# Help needed in fish identification

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology

Please help me identify these fish. I looked around but wasn't able to determine its species.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No sure id, but the shape woudl hint at some kind of archerfish, I'd say. On a seperate note, I would think the bowl is way too small for them...

Comment: We would actually count these as off topic for fish identification. I will see what people say. The images are also blurry.

Comment: would you need to have it be identified? There are plenty of stores that handle fish that could tell you.

Comment: It's look like platy to me.

Comment: Hi guys, I have relinked the pictures. No need to close now I guess?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like southern platyfish (Xiphophorus maculatus) to me.

[image]

Courtesy: http://aquaticszone.blogspot.in/2011_04_01_archive.html

Comment: My first thought as well, and a very common aquarium fish. Might be similar closely related species though.